# Sistema noticias PHP - Noticia sem imagem da erro e não deleta

Tags: php, mysqli, delete

Olá!

Com a ajuda de alguns amigos aqui, montei um sistema de noticias.
Mas acabei me deparando com um problema.
Quando preciso deletar a noticia utilizo o seguinte codigo:

```
<?php
    include_once("../../conexao/conexao.php");
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $diretorio = "../../../style/images/noticias/";  
    $pegaValores = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT imagem FROM noticias WHERE id = $id");  
    $imagem = mysqli_fetch_object($pegaValores);  
    $imagemQueVaiDeletada = $diretorio . $imagem->imagem;   
    $deleta = unlink($imagemQueVaiDeletada);    
    if($deleta): mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM noticia WHERE id='$id'");  
    endif; 
?>
```

Tudo oK, código funciona, deleta a imagem do diretório e apaga do banco MySQL

Mas, se não há imagem cadastrada na noticia e nem na pasta.

Gera erro na linha `$deleta = unlink($imagemQueVaiDeletada);`

Warning: unlink(../../../style/images/institucional/): Permission denied

Não é problema de permissão, é porque o arquivo não existe no diretório. Pois se preencho na mão o nome do arquivo no banco e coloco a imagem no diretório, deleta tudo correto, deleta a imagem do diretório e a linha do banco.

Pois existem algumas noticias que não possuem imagem, nem no banco nem no diretório.

Qual a verificação devo fazer tanto no diretório e no banco?
Acredito que se não há imagem no banco, não haverá no diretório.

Como verificar se há dados na coluna "imagem" do banco. Se estiver vazia deleta sem passar pelo código de deletar no diretório.
Se há dados na coluna passa para deletar no diretório.

Alguém puder ajudar.
Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

O código está em linha, então ele vai verificar linha por linha. Assim, seria interessante verificar se o arquivo existe. Utilize algo como If(is_file(...)){ ... Caso exista delete entra em ação, do contrário não faz nada. https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.is-file.php

Comment: Sim, mas ai estou verificando no diretório?
Tipo algo assim:
`if(!empty ($_FILES['VARIAVEL))`

Mas gostaria de verificar na linha do banco. 
Se estiver a coluna da tabela vazia, deleta a linha sem precisar verificar o diretório.
Se a coluna estiver com dados passa para deletar no diretorio.

Ou uma solução mais simples.